# How to fetch related product or similar product in magento Soap Apiv2

Tags: java, android, magento, soap

I am developing an Android eCommerce application with backend magento and using SOAP APIv2 in which i have to show related product or similar product at the bottom of my particular product what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

may this help you. Please check the link
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34292/magento-related-products

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a method in API that get a list of related products. The code above show you how to do that in PHP, but if you use a client to make this in Java will be this method:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

$result = $proxy->catalogProductLinkList($sessionId, 'related', '1');
var_dump($result);
```

You can get other types of products just change the parameter 'related' to one of this list:

```
array
  0 => string 'related' (length=7)
  1 => string 'up_sell' (length=7)
  2 => string 'cross_sell' (length=10)
  3 => string 'grouped' (length=7)
```

I hope thats help you.

Comment: please Carlos can you visit this url   http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154893/how-to-show-related-product-in-magento-soap-api-v2  here i have written related product script, could you please check that weather it is right or not....?

Comment: Hi, I send you a simple code that get all related products for productId = 45. Is on magent Stack http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154893/how-to-show-related-product-in-magento-soap-api-v2/155305#155305